# Why webdriver.Chrome() does not accept 'service' keyword

Tags: python, pytest

I have upgraded Selenium to 4.1.0. but still, receive 'Unexpected argument'`

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

s1 = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
s2 = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())


@pytest.fixture()
def setup(browser):
    if browser == 'chrome':
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s1)
    elif browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(GeckoDriverManager().install())
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s1)
    return driver
```

With the 'unexpected argument' error I can run my tests through pycharm without any errors/warnings but can not via cmd(receive an error)

According to my investigation, it should be related to the selenium version but after upgrading the problem still actual

In case I am trying a method like Firefox, a warning is reported that is put in service.

Comment: It is likely that you have more than one Python installation, and you upgraded `selenium` in only one if them, and your console environment is using the other.

Comment: Interesting. And how can I check this?

Comment: In PyCharm look at the interpreter that is set for your project. From `cmd` run Python and look at the version in the flowerpot the interpreter displays  at startup. To find out where the default  `pip` installs stuff, do `pip --version`. To find out if there are other instances of `pip`, do  `where pip`. To install a package in a specific installation of Python, navigate to the `Scripts` folder of that installation and issue the  `pip` command from there.

Comment: I have checked with print(selenium.__version__) and pip freeze version is the same. Also, the version in PyCharm also is OK.                                                                                                    PS pycharm show me the error 'Unexpected argument' during writing code.

Comment: Well, if it is not a version problem, maybe you should believe the messages.